# Change Default Starting Domain For .NET Website Project

Tags: visual-studio-2005, hosts, vs-web-site-project, domain-aliasing

I have a Website project that I'm trying to debug using Fiddler.  Fiddler doesn't track traffic from localhost, so I created another alias in my hosts file to use instead of localhost.  Now I would like to have my project use the fiddler.local.com instead of localhost when I run my project.  Is there a way to do this?

i.e. http://fiddler.local.com:1100/photoTest/default.aspx vs. http://localhost:1100/photoTest/default.aspx

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577772/force-visual-studio-to-start-development-server-using-the-hostname-localhost-wi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler will track traffic from localhost, just use http://localhost./yoursite/default.aspx

Other than that, you right click on the website project in your solution, then select properties. The properties page will then appear, so select the web tab on the left hand side. There you will see an option to use IIS when debugging, which, when selected will enable you to set the url to use.