# What is the magic behind that DOT which makes Fiddler work?

Tags: dns, localhost, fiddler

It took me a while to learn that I have to put a dot after the "localhost" in the URL so that I can use fiddler with my development server.

Why do I need to put this dot here to make fiddler work for my local:

http://localhost**.**:1888/MyPage.aspx

What does it stand for?

thanks

Comment: highly recommend http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox

Comment: Similar problem, but I think my work around is much more elegant: go to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\` and open up a file named `hosts`, append this as a new line `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain`. From now on access your local development site as `http://localhost.localdomain/` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not that you're making fiddler work, but you're making Internet Explorer work.  Internet Explorer is written specifically to bypass the proxy server for "localhost" .  By attaching a trailing dot, you're providing a valid DNS name that does not match the mechanism within IE that checks the domain (IE does a `stricmp(userdata, "localhost")` or equivalant).

Comment: Yup.  You could set the HookWithPAC registry key as an alternative to sticking the dot after localhost, because when a PAC script is used instead of a direct proxy registration, LOCALHOST requests are eligible for proxying.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577772/force-visual-studio-to-start-development-server-using-the-hostname-localhost-wi

Comment: More info on: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp as well. You can check the tıtle: "Why don't I see traffic sent to http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1?"

Answer (score 0):

localhost. just makes the hostname visible to Fiddler; otherwise, IE bypasses proxies.

You can also substitute "ipv4.fiddler" for "localhost" -- which can help prevent confusion, since the dot is easy to miss.