# How do I use Fiddler to listen to the asp.net development server (i.e. cassini)?

Tags: wcf, localhost, cassini, fiddler, asp.net-development-serv

I am attempting to debug a (RESTful) WCF app using Fiddler.  I run my project via VS IDE - which launches my app in the ASP.NET Development Server  aka  Cassini.  I then launch Fiddler and in the Request Builder tab enter the following:  "http://localhost:1066/GeneralService/sections/summary"  with GET as the http method.

Fiddler responds with "[Fiddler] Connection to localhost failed.
Exception Text: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ::1:1066  "

Is there some way for me to debug an app running on Cassini?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577772/force-visual-studio-to-start-development-server-using-the-hostname-localhost-wi for the duplicate version of this question; that thread lists all possible approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the url to `http://ipv4.fiddler:1066/GeneralService/sections/summary` to enable fiddler to listen on `localhost`

Answer (score 8):

One neat trick is just to add a period(.) after the word localhost.  No other config neccesary.

Comment: woah. that works. Network magic.Someone got an explanation why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the integrated traffic monitor built into CassiniDev. It can be run stand-alone or as a direct drop-in replacement for VS 2008/2010 development servers.

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=cassinidev&DownloadId=123367](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=cassinidev&DownloadId=123367)
[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=cassinidev&DownloadId=123366](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=cassinidev&DownloadId=123366)