# Fiddler, localhost, IIS, PHP and GData

Tags: php, iis, fiddler, gdata

I have managed to get Fiddler monitoring my localhost traffic by specifying my machine name. I am using IIS7 (localhost) on Vista business. I'm developing using PHP and am currently using the Zend GData framework to communicate with Google Calendar.

I am not seeing any communication between the IIS/Localhost server and the Google service. How can I see requests between my localhost IIS server and the external Google server. Obviously, I am seeing the result of the interaction in the browser but not the request/response between IIS and Google that is orchestrated by my PHP script and the Zend GData framework.

Can Fiddler do this? Any help or advice would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Geester

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your IIS code runs in a different user account, and hence ASP.NET must be directly configured to point at Fiddler. See http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-DOTNET and [Fiddler not sniffing SOAP traffic from ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783172/fiddler-not-sniffing-soap-traffic-from-asp-net-website)

Comment: Neither of those solutions work for PHP since PHP does not use a web.config file.