# Monitoring traffic to Cassini on localhost

Tags: asp.net, http, monitoring, fiddler, cassini

I'm experiencing some really odd timeout issues when running a ASP.NET 2.0 project on Cassini on localhost, and I don't have enough data to get a clue of what's going on.

Is there a way to monitor localhost traffic to Cassini, either using some specific development tool or a general-purpose monitoring app such as fiddler?

Just to pre-empt some answers I'm already aware of:

- Normally I can use the well-known [dot-hack](http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2008/01/10/tip-for-using-fiddler-on-localhost.aspx) for using fiddler to monitor localhost traffic, but with Cassini I get the following error message in the browser:

  > [Fiddler] Connection to localhost. failed. Exception Text: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ::1:3213
- Fiddler also listens to localhost on http://ipv4.fiddler:port, and I can intercept the traffic. But when I do this the timeout issues don't occur!

Any other tools or fiddler workarounds welcome! Thanks!

Edit: **Oops.** This question had [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937805/how-do-i-use-fiddler-to-listen-to-the-asp-net-development-server-i-e-cassini)... [Twice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826134/how-to-display-localhost-traffic-in-fiddler-while-debugging-an-asp-net-applicatio). Didn't come up on search or suggestions.  The solution found in the second thread is to use the dot-hack with ip-address (http://127.0.0.1.:port/ instead of "localhost". This question may be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're generally better off using http://ipv4.fiddler as it makes it more explicit what you're trying to do.

Comment: this approach has proven problematic

Comment: Given that thousands of people do this daily, more details would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While fiddler ignores requests to **localhost**, it listens to **127.0.0.1.** (note the trailing dot):

So this won't work:

> http://localhost:1234/

But this will:

> http://127.0.0.1.:1234/

Comment: Answering my own question in case someone lands here via google.

Comment: Fiddler doesn't "ignore" requests to localhost; IE and .NET just refuse to proxy requests for Localhost (other browsers don't). See http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic

Answer (score 0):

[**CassiniDev**](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/) is an open source project that was developed to fill in all the blanks left by WebDev.WebServer/Cassini.

You will find this issue handled as well as many others.

It works well as a stand-alone server, as an in-process server suitable for testing and embedding and, most notably, as a direct replacement for the Visual Studio 2008/2010 dev servers.

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=cassinidev&DownloadId=123367](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=cassinidev&DownloadId=123367)

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=cassinidev&DownloadId=123366](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=cassinidev&DownloadId=123366)