# With firebug stop loading so can see requests

Tags: post, get, firebug

I am trying to analyze a POST request using firebug.  Using the net panel I can see the request, however when the POST has success the page then reloads and I only have a couple of seconds to actually look at the request and see what is going on.  Is there a way I can pause it much like when analyzing scripts using this tool?

Comment: remove the refresh of the page from your code.

Comment: not an option or of course i would do that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a "Persist" button on some of the tabs in Firebug. Just make sure to click it before doing your post.

[edit] Second row, third button from the left, on the Console and Net tabs.

Comment: hmm... thought this worked, but it doesnt.. upon reload everything disappears

Comment: Strange, I use that feature all the time... make sure you enable it in the same tab that you are using it in and check to see if it is collapsed (newer versions of FireBug will group/collapse subsequent requests in the Net tab).

Comment: aha! i did not realize it was grouping them like that.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Even better, if you're on Windows you can use Fiddler - an amazing and free HTTP debugger developed by some important guy on the Microsoft IE team.

With it you can conditionally intercept GET or POST requests, inspect and change parameters, break on responses, change responses (headers or body), reissue old requests and generally screw with your application during development.

Simply one of the most useful web development tools. Ever.

May require a little tweaking for localhost - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577772/force-visual-studio-to-start-development-server-using-the-hostname-localhost-wi)

Comment: agreed I do love fiddler +1.. i was just looking for a quickie solution as i was sure there was something I was missing in firebug.. as Andrew showed me

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to remove the refresh of the page from your code.

Then run your code to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web developer tools plugin for Mozilla firefox, and disable meta redirects